# Named Pipe with C# Server C++ Client blocking Write

Tags: c#, c++, named-pipes

Trying to upgrade the server code to C# while keeping the client the same which is using C++ for named pipe data exchange in both directions.

The C++ Client connects, sends an initial string and a request for data.
Data is sent back and received.
Then the next Write command hits the Disconnect() function:

```
retCode = WriteFile (m_hPipe, cCmd, strlen(cCmd), &bytesWritten, &m_OverLapWrt);

if (!retCode) {                   // Wait on overlapped if need be.
    lastError = GetLastError();
    if (lastError == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
        retCode = WaitForSingleObject (m_hEventWrt, 5000);
        if (retCode != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            SetLastError(ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE);
            Disconnect();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else {
        SetLastError(lastError);
        Disconnect();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The C# Server

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream("link", PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances,                                                  PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.None);
                                                    
StreamString ss = new StreamString(pipeServer);

// Wait for a client to connect
pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

try
{
    var response = ss.ReadString(60);
    ti.m_cMessage = response + " connected on thread " + ti.m_iThreadID;
   
}
// Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken
// or disconnected.
catch (IOException e)
{
    ti.m_cMessage = string.Format ("Not connected on thread {0}. Error {1}", ti.m_iThreadID,e.Message);
}
Do
{
    if (ti.m_bWrite)
    {
        try
        {
            ss.WriteString(ti.m_cOutBuf);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            ti.m_cMessage = string.Format("Write exception {0}.", e.Message);
            goto PipeError;
        }
        ti.m_bWrite = false;
    }
    if (ss.DataReady() == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            c = ss.ReadChar();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            ti.m_cMessage = string.Format("Read Char exception {0}.", e.Message);
            ti.m_iMessage = 1;
            goto PipeError;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Process char data
    }
} while (pipeServer.IsConnected);

public char ReadChar()
{
    char[] c = new char[1];
    try
    {
        int error = sr.Read(c, 0, 1);
        if (error == -1)
            return ' ';
        else
            return c[0];
    }
    catch
    {
        return ' ';
    }
}
public int WriteString(string outString)
{
    byte[] outBuffer = streamEncoding.GetBytes(outString);
    int len = outBuffer.Length;
    try
    {
        ioStream.Write(outBuffer, 0, len);
        ioStream.Flush();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

    return outBuffer.Length;
}
```

When the Client has the issue writing, the Server has pipeServer.IsConnected == true.

Comment: Is the initial request string 60 characters long? I think about what happens, if it is shorter... When I did protocols for named pipes in the past, I usually sent a 4 byte length first, so the receiver could read the exact amount of what is coming next.

Comment: Have to agree with @BitTickler. Reading a hard-coded number of bytes while the sender is using `strlen()` for the length to send is either a bug now or it will be by next week.

Comment: It is shorter, but it makes it past that part of the code and gets to the Readchar function where it reads in one command request from the client. That Write works from the client but the 2nd one fails.

Comment: So what error is WriteFile() receiving when it fails?

Comment: WaitForSingleObject returns STATUS_TIMEOUT

Comment: Do I need to use PipeOptions.Asynchronous on the C# server since my C++ client is using Overlapped IO?